# Firebase change app name which display on google sign in alert?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, alert, google-signin

I have a firebase project, but somehow I mistype the app name, is there a way to change the app name which displays on the google sign in alert? ￼

[image: The Google alert screenshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should change product name in your project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

This might change the name:

- Go to the firebase console and select your project
- Press the gear in the left sidemenu, choose "Project settings"
- You will see the project name with a pencil next to it.
- Click it to edit the name and save it.

Comment: Doesn't change the name in the dialog for me. Only changing info.plist solves it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same & solved as follows.

Go to Xcode > Click 'Target' project > Under 'Info'
Changed the 'Value' of 'Bundle Name'

Also, change the 'Bundle display Name'

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `CFBundleName` in the `Runner/Info.plist`

or for Android is

```
<application
        android:label="AppName"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `info.plist` file, check what it says under CFBundleName.

[image]

Here, you may see `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`.  You may find that variable set in your `project.pbxproj` file.

in `project.pbxproj`, search for `PRODUCT_NAME`.  There may be two - one for debug, one for release.  Set them both to your desired name for each build type.  Then rebuild the app, and you will the new name as expected.

[image]