# Modify AppAuth alert

Tags: ios, swift, appauth

I am using AppAuth (0.95) to access google mail on my IOS app. Before redirecting to google sign-in, i get an alert with this message.

`'Appname' wants to use google.com to sign in. This allows the app and website to share information about you`

[image: 'appname' wants to use google.com to sign in.]

Looks like `Appname` is the apps bundle name. Is it possible to change it to the apps display name. Or not have the alert at all?

Comment: you can use display name instead of bundle identifier

Comment: When creating the `OIDAuthorizationRequest`? I am using this [example](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/Examples/Example-iOS_Swift-Carthage/Source/AppAuthExampleViewController.swift). At what point do i specify the display name?

Comment: you have to change the app display name in google console your project display name and that affect directly here

Comment: doesn't look like there is anything on google console to change the display name on this alert. I can change the `consent screen` which shows up after i click `continue` on this screen

Comment: do you have any screen shots or anything that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can go to "Build Settings" and change the "Product Name."

[image]

There's also a similar question here:

- [Firebase change app name which display on google sign in alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50604741/826435)

Answer (score 0):

The alert dialog is as a result of using [SFAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession). It cannot be edited or bypassed. Unless you rename your project