# How to change displayed project name in authentication with google,firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-authentication

This is my default UI for authentication with Google.
I'm using IOS emulator and i don't know how to change project name.
Can you show me how to change project name? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [renaming your project](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137752):

> The project card displays the name of your project (visible only to project members) and the project's public-facing name.
>
> The public-facing name is the name presented to users when they are shown any public instances of your project. For example, the public-facing name displays on emails that your users receive after creating an account with your app.
>
> To edit either of your project's names:
>
> 1. Click the pencil icon next to the name for either Project name or Public-facing name.
> 2. Enter a new name.
> 3. Click Save.

Also see:

- [Firebase change app name which display on google sign in alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604741/firebase-change-app-name-which-display-on-google-sign-in-alert)
- [How to change the app name for firebase authentication (what the user sees)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135993/how-to-change-the-app-name-for-firebase-authentication-what-the-user-sees)

Comment: simple work . Thank you sir so much !