# Firebase Project Settings - cannot locate ability to update public facing name

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

According to this: [Customize account management emails and SMS messages](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714)

I should be able to change the public facing name by going to Project Overview > Project Settings > General Tab > Public Facing name

But this item simply doesn't exist within the Settings > General tab. My verification emails (which are uneditable) display %APP_NAME%, which is clearly my Project ID (eg. AppName-2bask3), but I need the Project name (eg. AppName).

Here's a previous answer that I followed from 2022. [How to change displayed project name in authentication with google,firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106467/how-to-change-displayed-project-name-in-authentication-with-google-firebase)

I've read the docs, other SO answers, and they all describe a setting that simply doesn't exit anymore.

Comment: *firebaser here* I still can find the "Public-facing name" in older projects, but not in recent projects indeed. I'm not sure where it went, so am asking around.

Comment: Much appreciated! This project was started in Sept. 2023 for ref.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Adding that this answer seems to help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188427/where-did-the-public-settings-of-a-firebase-project-go?rq=2). I added Google provider, then removed it, and I can now see the setting.

Comment: Aha, I never realized that - but usually indeed have the Google auth provider enabled on my projects. Can we close this as a duplicate of the question that helped you find it then, so that others can more easily follow the link you spent time finding?